# Microphone and headphones no longer detected in my computer

Tags: microphone, headphones, hardware-detection

I am having problems with my microphone as well as my headphones.
Whenever I try to use my headphones not only they are not detected, but I need to reboot my computer with them inserted if I want them to be detected. Simultaneously, I have discovered that my microphone, both my computer's and my headphones' are not at all detected whenever I am on a Skype or Zoom meeting. I have been trying to solve this for three days now.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is caused by an audio driver, you can try uninstalling your audio driver via Device Manager, then restart your pc, and Windows will reinstall a driver for your audio device.

Press the Windows logokey and R at the same time to open the Run box.
Type devmgmt.msc and press Enter to access Device Manager.

[image]

Expand Sound, video and game controllers.

[image]

Right-click on your audio device, and select Uninstall device.

[image]

Click Uninstall as confirmation.

[image]

Restart your computer, and Windows will automatically install a new audio driver.
Check if your pc can now detect your headphones.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, and I still get the same problem with my headphones that are connected by jack... If I insert them right after rebooting my computer I can hear through them, but once I take them off and try to re-insert them, they are no longer detected and I hear the sound from my computer's speakers...

Comment: @Wallflower If you use Realtek HD Audio Manager, try disabling front panel jack detection.

Comment: Tried this too, doesn't not work

Comment: I really do not know what's wrong, lol. It was all good until it started to not work at all, both my headphones and my compyter's mike. I've tested my headphones and all is good...

Answer (score 1):

The headphones are connected by jack, USB, wireless or some other plug?

Usually the procedure as follow shall work:

1_ try to remind yourself what was installed, updated at day 0 of problem, and if possible return to state before installation.

2_ go to System>Device manager (or RunDll32.exe devmgr.dll DeviceManager_Execute), switch off/on sound card device, and check for device errors.

3_ if problem persist uninstall and install again sound card driver, or headset driver if needed.

Comment: Connected by jack, and I still have the same problem...